# merging two canvases

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

If I have 2 canvases:

The first canvas (canvas1) is the basic one that  contains text and will be saved as an image (canvas1 + canvas2).

The second one (canvas2) contains an image that can be moved within canvas2 through `keydown`. The code works fine with canvas2 as I cleared first canvas2 then `context2.drawImage(img,x,y)`.

But If i write( `canvas1.drawImage(canvas2, 0, 0)` then the movements of the image  is shown in canvas 1. And if i said clear canvas 1 then  `canvas1.drawImage(canvas2, 0, 0)` the text will disappear.

So my question is: how can I draw canvas 2 on canvas 1 when the user finishes moving the image not during the image's movement?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not entirely clear why you would want to do this, but if you want Canvas 1 to always display canvas 1+2, then you can always save the contents of Canvas 1:

1. Draw Canvas 1 to an in-memory canvas (call it canvas3)
2. Draw Canvas 2 to Canvas 1
3. Draw Canvas 3 (which was Canvas 1 saved) back to Canvas 1

http://jsfiddle.net/Jvgxb/14/

Answer (score 0):

Try to make two DIVs over each other. each of those DIVs should contain one of your canvases :)